# Using Application.Close() from a Windows Form

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am making a Windows Form Application with several forms, and I want to be able to close the entire application from any of the Forms. My main problem is that the `System.Windows.Forms.Application` class, used in the `Program.cs` class is `Private`. I would like any of the forms to be able to use it directly with something like `Program.Application.Exit();`. I realize that I could just make a `ApplicationExit` method within the `Program` class, and just call that, but that means that I will need to make a new one if I want to use any other methods from the `Application` class.

This is what I have right now:

```
public static class Application
{
    public static void EnableVisualStyles()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    }
    public static void Run()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
    }
    public static void Exit()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }
    public static void SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(bool defaultValue)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(defaultValue);
    }
}
```

But with this I need to add each of the methods individually, and if I want to be able to manage variables I need to start using a ton of `{get; set;}` statements. This works, but I would like to know if there is a way to just make a class called `Application` within the `Program` class that directly inherits or imports the `System.Windows.Forms.Application` class.

Comment: You are wrong , System.Windows.Forms.Application class is not private (neither is the Exit method)...You can call it from wherever you want

Comment: Thank you. Had not realized that calling Application.Exit(); was referring to the entire application, and not just the specific Form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is correct

```
Application.Exit()
```

Terminates the entire application.
If you want to close only the form you must only call the Close() method of the Form class